# How to do sum at 2 cell after the last used cell in column and column has blank cells in between?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, spreadsheet

[Get Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrjQB.png)

As shown in picture, I have **two columns J and K** to do sum at **two cells after last used cell**, Problem is there are sometimes *randomly oriented empty cells* due to which sum stops in between.

Also, the sum cell of J column should have **Green text** and the sum cell of K column should have **Red text**. Plz include this into your code, I don't know how to do it.

I am beginner in vba, it's just my fifth day...

Here is what I have tried till now...

At first, I thought it will be easy to do sum, just finding last used cell in column and then applying sum formula. So I tried the code below...

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
 
 LastRow = Range("J2").End(xlDown).Row
 Cells(LastRow + 2, "J").Formula = "=SUM(J2:J" & LastRow & ")"
```

Then I realised that it's not gonna be that easy in my case. What I found was when I played macro, the sum was done, but only in between the cells. So, I tried all my programming knowledge and thought to apply condition that if cell contains value then add that value to variable and if cell is empty then move to the next cell... But I don't have idea how to do it... Still I am providing the code which I tried...

```
Sub SumData()
 Dim sumOne As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long

 LastRow = Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row
 sumOne = 0
 
        Dim MyRng As Range
        Set MyRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("F")
        Dim cellRng As Range
Sum:
        For Each cellRng In MyRng.Cells
             If cellRng.Value <> "" Then
            sumOne = sumOne + cellRng.Value
            
            Cells(LastRow + 2, "F").Value = sumOne
        
            GoTo Sum
        End If
            Range("A2").Select
        Next
        
End Sub
```

With the codes above I was trying to practice with data in F column so column F is not problem...
And I think there would be easier and better way to do it

Answer:
**Issue guided by Simon :** *To find the last row you were using xlDown. This means it searches from row 1 down until it finds an empty cell. You need to use xlUp so it searches from the bottom of the sheet upwards so it finds the true last cell.*

Comment: `"to do sum at two cells after last used cell"` Not sure exactly what you mean here.

Comment: Please provide code you have tried stating the issues you're facing. You need to demonstrate that you did your research before posting a question. Furthermore, please do not say things like *Plz help me* or *Plz be kind*. Everyone is here to help and be helped.

Comment: @Simon What I mean to say is suppose my sheet has 10 cells in J column then I want to sum that 10 cells and put the answer into 12th cell in the same column. And point to note is that there can be empty cells in between in the J column. Plz refer to the image if you want more clarity.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Okay I am providing the codes I used to do it in a while, I am really sorry and I understand your point.

Comment: Sum of one of the columns mentioned (J and or K) or from a different column?

Comment: Not sure what your problem with the empty cells is though? Sum either through VBA or regular formula just ignores blank cells so they shouldn't be a problem. Ignores in the sense they are empty so there is nothing to sum.

Comment: Looking at your formula. To find the last row you were using `xlDown`. This means it searches from row 1 down until it finds an empty cell. You need to use `xlUp` so it searches from the bottom of the sheet upwards so it finds the true last cell.

Comment: @P.b In my case it's just for Columns mentioned. Means the column J and K only. But yes we can do the same with little changes in code below provided by Simon, if We want to sum different column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this and see if it's what you're after.

```
Sub SumColumns()

Dim lRowJ As Long, lRowK As Long

lRowJ = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRowK = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("J" & lRowJ + 2)
    .Value = Application.Sum(Range("J1:J" & lRowJ))
    .Font.Color = vbGreen
End With
With Range("K" & lRowK + 2)
    .Value = Application.Sum(Range("K1:K" & lRowK))
    .Font.Color = vbRed
End With

End Sub
```

Here's another example using a specific sheet name, without the `With` and using `RGB` for the colour:

```
Dim lRowJ As Long, lRowK As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Name of your sheet
lRowJ = ws.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRowK = ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("J" & lRowJ + 2).Value = Application.Sum(Range("J1:J" & lRowJ))
ws.Range("J" & lRowJ + 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 150, 0)
    
ws.Range("K" & lRowK + 2).Value = Application.Sum(Range("K1:K" & lRowK))
ws.Range("K" & lRowK + 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Ohh I got it, I was using For each loop, instead of which I should have used With... You are awesome... Thank you for help @Simon

Comment: @Readers vbGreen is too bright so I changed .Font.Color = vbGreen to .Font.ColorIndex = 10... If you are also not fan of vbGreen as font then you can do the same to get dark green...

Comment: Well the `With` isn't necessary it just helps the code be tidier. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) . It's the official Microsoft docs for pretty much all the VBA functions. I found it very useful starting out and sometimes still do.

Comment: Well yes it's just the default green I went with. You could also use RGB `.Font.Color = RGB(0, 150, 0)`

Comment: Yes you are right, with RGB we can use wide range of custom colors... And thank you for helping me to understand use of with, I visited the site you suggested and I got to know something new.